# How to use SUM() OVER (partition by)?

Tags: sql, window-functions

Imagine, from 1st to 3rd november you have sold a certain amount of goods (there are two types A and B), and now you need to determine how much was sold in total for the day.

How can I query last 2 columns (sum and quantity for date) that my table looks like this?:

```
Date         Type           Quantity      Amount    Sum_Quantity  Sum_Amount
01-11          A               2            100          5            300 
01-11          B               3            200          5            300
02-11          A               1            700          3            950
02-11          B               2            250          3            950
03-11          A               2            600          7            800
03-11          B               5            200          7            800
```

And how can I query, if I want to take the results partitioned by month?

Comment: Are you sure your desired output should be like this ? You want i.E two rows for `01-11` . Giving some table schema and output would be more helpful to us. So far, for me your are looking for this `SELECT Date, Type, SUM(Quantity) Quantity, SUM(Amount) Amount From TableA Group by Date,Type`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date,
       type,
       quantity,
       amount,
       -- Partition by date
       SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY date) AS sum_quantity_date_part,
       SUM(amount)   OVER (PARTITION BY date) AS sum_amount_date_part,

       -- Partition by month
       SUM(quantity) OVER (
           PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date),
                        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)
       ) AS sum_quantity_month_part,

       SUM(amount)   OVER (
           PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date),
                        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)
       ) AS sum_amount_month_part

FROM sales
ORDER BY date, type
;
```

Comment: You should mention this query can't be executed on most DBMS.